# How to await a byte[]

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a MVC 4 app. One of the things it does is send an email by calling another service using the `WebClient` like so:

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string requestData = serializer.Serialize(new
{
    EventID = 1,
    SubscriberID = studentId,
    ToList = loginModel.EmailAddress,
    TemplateParamVals = strStudentDetails,
});

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
    var result = await client.UploadData(URI, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData));
}
```

I wanted to make use of `UploadDataAsync` but got the error:

> An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle.

So I thought of creating a wrapper function & making it asynchronous while still using `UploadDataAsync`.

```
private async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(long studentId, LoginModel loginModel)
{
    try
    {
        string URI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommunicationmanagerURL"] + "PostUserEvent";
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        string requestData = serializer.Serialize(new
        {
            EventID = 1,
            SubscriberID = studentId,
            ToList = loginModel.EmailAddress,
            TemplateParamVals = strStudentDetails,
        });

        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
            var result = await client.UploadData(URI, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData));    
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log exceptions ...
    }
}
```

This doesn't build and gives the error:

> Cannot await 'byte[]'

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I've a feeling you'll still run into issues when you try to call your wrapper, though.

Answer (score 1):

you can not await a synchrone function, you have to call the [..]Async one:

```
var result = await client.UploadDataAsync(URI, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData));
```

The function you call returns a `byte[]`, which is of course not awaitable.
`UploadDataAsync` returns a `Task<byte[]>` instead, this one you want to use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms144225(v=vs.110).aspx

edit:
The Method seems to return `void`, which is kind of awaitable, too.. in terms of fire and forget.

Comment: The UploadDataAsync method does not return a Task<byte[]>, it uses UploadDataCompleted event. Use UploadDataTaskAsync instead.

Comment: you're right, I've edited my answer in the meantime. I won't edit my answer any more but upvote yours.

Answer (score 0):

The `UploadData` method you are using in your sample code is a synchronous operation. As the compiler is saying, you cannot await a synchronous operation. The problem is not the `byte[]` type but the operation itself.

If you want to use await, you'll need to use an asynchronous operation. [`WebClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) offers two asynchronous versions of the `UploadData` method :

- [`UploadDataAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms144225%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [`UploadDataTaskAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh193934%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

To properly use the await functionnality, you'll need to use `UploadDataTaskAsync`.

EDIT : My first answer was about the warning you got from the compiler. What you are trying to do is wrap the call to the synchronous operation in a Task to make it asynchronous.

You can achieve this by creating your own `Task` and returning it :

```
private async Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(long studentId, LoginModel loginModel)
{
    Task<bool> uploadTask = Task.Factory.StartNew<bool>(
        () =>
        {
            try
            {
                string URI = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommunicationmanagerURL"] + "PostUserEvent";
                var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

                string requestData = serializer.Serialize(new
                {
                    EventID = 1,
                    SubscriberID = studentId,
                    ToList = loginModel.EmailAddress,
                    TemplateParamVals = strStudentDetails,
                });

                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/json";
                    var result = client.UploadData(URI, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestData));

                    return true;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Log exceptions ...
                return false;
            }
        });

    return uploadTask;
}
```

Comment: Tried that and ended up getting asynchronous operation cannot be started ... exception so went with the wrapper solution

Comment: I see, the problem the compiler is warning you about is trying to await a method that is not await-able. What you're currently trying to do is using a Task to get your method asynchronous. You should wrap your call to UploadData in a task and return it.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying reason is a bit complicated; it has to do with how [EAP components](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228969%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (such as `WebClient`) notify their platform that they are doing work.

The easiest solution is to replace `WebClient` with `HttpClient`.